# chart.js time series skips days

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a very simple bar graph where each data point consists of a date (day) and a number. Maybe the only speciality is that not every date is covered (i.e. for some days there is no data point).

When drawing the graph, only those days are shown that have a data point associated with them. All other days are simply omitted. So the x axis is not evenly distributed and skips values.

[image: Faulty graph]

How can I make sure the X axis is truly linear and does not leave any days out?

PS: This is how my graph is defined:

```
chartData.datasets[0].data.push( {t: new Date('2019-02-01'), y: value});
// And so on...

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: chartData,
        options: {
            annotation: {
                annotations: []
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
             },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    unitStepSize: 1,
                    distribution: 'series',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'day'
                    },
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working solution to this issue, adapted for new version of Chart.js **v3.x**

Chart.js **v3.2.1** (not backwards compatible with **v2.xx**)

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('timeSeriesChart').getContext('2d');

const chartData = [
  {x:'2019-01-08', y: 4},
  {x:'2019-01-13', y: 28},
  {x:'2019-01-14', y: 8},
  {x:'2019-01-15', y: 18},
  {x:'2019-01-16', y: 68},
  {x:'2019-01-18', y: 48},
  {x:'2019-01-19', y: 105},
  {x:'2019-01-21', y: 72},
  {x:'2019-01-23', y: 36},
  {x:'2019-01-24', y: 48},
  {x:'2019-01-25', y: 17},
  {x:'2019-01-28', y: 30},
  {x:'2019-01-29', y: 28},
  {x:'2019-01-30', y: 25},
  {x:'2019-01-31', y: 18},
  {x:'2019-02-04', y: 25},
  {x:'2019-02-05', y: 22},
  {x:'2019-02-06', y: 17},
  {x:'2019-02-07', y: 15}
];

const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
  datasets: [{
    data: chartData,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(189,0,53)'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {  
      legend: {  //watch out: new syntax in v3.2.0, `legend` within `plugins`
        display: false
      },
      title: {   //watch out: new syntax in v3.2.0, `title` within `plugins`
        display: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {  //watch out: new syntax in v3.2.0 for xAxis
        type: 'timeseries', // `time`  vs `timeseries` later in images
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        },
        ticks: { // Edit: added this to avoid overlapping - thanks for comment
          minRotation: 85, // <-- just try any number
          maxRotation: 90  // <-- just try any number
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
  <!-- gets you latest version of Chart.js (now at v3.2.1) --> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-moment"></script>
  <!-- for x-Axis type 'time' or 'timeseries' to work, you need additional libraries --> 
  <!-- (like moment.js and its adapter) --> 

<div>
    <canvas id="timeSeriesChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Time** Cartesian Axis

```
x: {
     type: 'time'
```

Makes x-Axis "linear" as you requested, days without data are still displayed

Source: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html

[image: Time Cartesian Axis]

**Time Series** Axis

```
x: {
     type: 'timeseries'
```

Makes data-points equidistant and justifies x-Axis accordingly for bars to show equally distributed

Source: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/timeseries.html

[image: Time Series Axis]

**Edit**: following avoiding **overlapping of x-Axis ticks** in reply to comment:
[image: timeseries without overlapping x-Axis ticks]

So far to show difference between types `time` and `timeseries`

Comment: Hi, do you know of a way to prevent X axis ticks overlapping in type:timeseries like it happens on your example?

Comment: @Andyba very good comment of yours - thanks. I have just edited my code accordingly for you to see and try, adding `ticks: { minRotation: 85, maxRotation: 90}` which resolves overlapping of x-axis ticks. Again thanks for your valuable comment 

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue once, the solution that worked for me was first instantiating an array filled with 0s (My array held data for five working days, so I created array of size 5, filled with 0s. Then later on in code the array was overwritten if data for specific day existed. Otherwise it had the value 0).

I imagine this may work for you if the data you're passing is of known size, so you can create it beforehand and fill with 0s.

Bear in mind this may not be the best solution