# After form submit, function runs quickly and chart.js shows up for a second then goes away

Tags: javascript, fetch, chart.js, form-submit, chart.js3

I have a Javascript project where I receive Covid-19 Data from an API source. The user types in the country they would like to see data for (from March 2020 to today) and then the data is graphed onto the screen using chart.js. I add an event listener to the input field where the user types in the country and retrieve data that that way. However, when I call my function to graph the data ( graphIt() ), the function happens for one second and then goes away. I understand why this may be happening since the function is only called once so it does it quickly. But, how would I keep the chart.js up for as long as I want? I'll put the important part of my code here!

**index.html**

```html
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'viewCasesChart/index.js' %}"></script>

        <div id="banner">
          <div id="banner_details">
            <h2>CoData</h2>
          </div>
        </div>    
    
       <div id="one_line">
         <div id="main_title">
           <h1>Covid-19 Data</h1>
         </div>
      
         <div id="user_query_data">
           <form id="country_form">
             <input type="text" placeholder="Country" id="country">
             <input type="submit" value="Search">
           </form>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div id="confirmed_graph">
         <canvas id="myChart" height="500" width="300"></canvas>
       </div>
```

**index.js**

```js
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    //make a global variable and put default value into it
    var country = "Italy";

    document.getElementById('country_form').addEventListener('submit', () => {
        var delayInMilliseconds = 100000; //
        country = document.getElementById('country').value;
        console.log("test 1", country);

        graphit();
    })
    
    async function graphit() {
        document.getElementById('myChart').style.display = "block";
        const dataset = await dataToGraph();
        
        console.log("dataset.xs", dataset.xs);
        console.log("dataset.ys", dataset.ys);

        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: dataset.xs,
                datasets: [{
                    label: `Covid 19 Confirmed cases in ${country}`,
                    data: dataset.ys,
                    backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
                    borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    fill: false,
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Confirmed Cases'
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Date'
                        }
                    }],
                }     
            }
        });
    };
    
    async function dataToGraph() {
        const xs = [];
        const ys = [];
        
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
        console.log("test 2", country);
        fetch(`https://webhooks.mongodb-stitch.com/api/client/v2.0/app/covid-19-qppza/service/REST-API/incoming_webhook/countries_summary?country=${country}&min_date=2020-04-22&max_date=${today}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(days => {
            days.forEach(day => {
                ys.push(day.confirmed);
                xs.push(day.date);
            })
        })
        
        console.log("xs", xs);
        console.log("ys", ys);
        console.log(`https://webhooks.mongodb-stitch.com/api/client/v2.0/app/covid-19-qppza/service/REST-API/incoming_webhook/countries_summary?country=${country}&min_date=2020-04-22&max_date=${today}`);
        return { xs, ys };
    };
}); // Edit: final closing brackets were missing
```

Comment: Must be missing some important code because when you make the chart it stays unless you destroy it yourself or hide the canvas

Comment: @JürgenFink, thank you so much for helping me. This solved all my issues I was having. You are a great teacher and explainer.

Comment: @Nayeemur Thank you - your question was interesting and therefore you got your first upvote from me  - congratulation and welcome to stack**overflow**. Note: I have just edited my answer adding feedback in UI when data is loading in background `myChart.data.datasets[0].label =  "loading ... ${country}"` within `dataToGraph(event)` function  ("loading ... Germany" for example ....). Remember, data is loading async in background as `fetch()` is async already - hence user knows that something is happening in background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `event.preventDefault()` was missing at form submit:

The reason why your chart does not appear is because the `event.preventDefault()` statement was missing in your form-submit. Hence, your form was sending an HTTP request (the default action) instead of executing your code.

I edited your code:

1. **added** `event.preventDefault()` at form submit
2. **declared variables** outside functions in order to avoid re-declaring repeatedly
3. **eliminated the `async` functionality**, as `fetch()` is a Promise (works like an async callback already, waiting for response from server)
4. **re-aranged order**:
   first call `dataToGraph()` at form submit (with `fetch()` for getting the data)
   then, when `fetch()`-API returned the data (async), call `graphit()`
5. **re-assign the data** to your chart (x- and y-axis data) and top label and then `update()` the chart
6. **adapted code** for final version of chart.js **v3.5.1** for improved performance (**v3.x** not compatible with **v2.x**):
7. **Load initial data** for Italy with `dataToGraph()`

**Run code snippet** and enter a country ('**I**taly', '**G**ermany', ....)
(case-sensitive: first letter has to be capital letter)

```js
// define all variables here outside functions
// in order to avoid re-assigning multiple times
let xs = [];
let ys = [];
let dataset = {};

dataset.xs = xs;
dataset.ys = ys;

let country = "Italy";

let today = new Date();
let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

const delayInMilliseconds = 100000;

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: dataset.xs,
        datasets: [{
            label: `Covid 19 Confirmed cases in ${country}`,
            data: dataset.ys,
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)'],
            borderWidth: 1,
            fill: false,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            yAxes: { // <-- axis is not array '[{' anymore, now object '{'
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Confirmed Cases'
                }
            },
            xAxes: { // <-- axis is not array '[{' anymore, now object '{'
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Date'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

// Load initial data for Italy
document.getElementById('country').value = country;
dataToGraph();

// here goes your Event-Listener with function as argument;
document.getElementById('country_form').addEventListener('submit', dataToGraph);

function dataToGraph(event) {
  if (event) event.preventDefault(); // <-- this was missing
  
  country = document.getElementById('country').value;
  // console.log("test 1", country);
  
  // give feedback to user that data is loading in background
  myChart.data.datasets[0].label =  `loading ... ${country}`;
  myChart.update();

  // set all variables to empty again:
  xs = [];
  ys = [];
  dataset = {};
  dataset.xs = xs;
  dataset.ys = ys;

  // fetch() is a Promise, i.e. it is like an async callback already,
  // hence no need to call async again.
  fetch(`https://webhooks.mongodb-stitch.com/api/client/v2.0/app/covid-19-qppza/service/REST-API/incoming_webhook/countries_summary?country=${country}&min_date=2020-04-22&max_date=${today}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(days => {
        days.forEach(day => {
            ys.push(day.confirmed);
            xs.push(day.date);
        });
        dataset.xs = xs;
        dataset.ys = ys;
        // console.log("xs", xs);
        // console.log("ys", ys);
        // console.log(`https://webhooks.mongodb-stitch.com/api/client/v2.0/app/covid-19-qppza/service/REST-API/incoming_webhook/countries_summary?country=${country}&min_date=2020-04-22&max_date=${today}`);
        // console.log(dataset);
        
        // now you can graph it
        graphit();
    })
    //return { xs, ys };
};


function graphit() {
    document.getElementById('myChart').style.display = "block";
    // const dataset = dataToGraph();

    // console.log("dataset.xs", dataset.xs);
    // console.log("dataset.ys", dataset.ys);

    // re-assign the datasets again (x- and y-axis)
    myChart.data.labels = dataset.xs;
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = dataset.ys;
    myChart.data.datasets[0].label =  `Covid 19 Confirmed cases in ${country}`;
    // now update your chart
    myChart.update();
};
```

```html
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script> -->

  <!-- get the latest version of Chart.js, now at v3.5.1 -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

  <div id="banner">
    <div id="banner_details">
      <h2>CoData</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

 <div id="one_line">
   <div id="main_title">
     <h1>Covid-19 Data</h1>
   </div>

   <div id="user_query_data">
     <form id="country_form">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Country" id="country">
       <input type="submit" value="Search">
     </form>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div id="confirmed_graph">
   <canvas id="myChart" height="500" width="300"></canvas>
 </div>
```

**Final Note:**
You might consider to add the `x: { type: 'time' ...` functionality to your chart, which would present the x-asis labels (dates) better. See my answer [chart.js time series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67308657/1155234) for more details.

### By the way: nice API - I like it

and welcome to stack**overflow**